# Transparent PictureBox over Panel

Tags: c#, label, transparency, opacity, picturebox

I have a problem because I wish to put a PictureBox on top of a Panel which is drawn as a Piano Stave. The Problem that I am having is when using `.Transparent` it is just giving me the Control colour form which is incorrect having a stave with lines across. What can I do?

EDIT:

How does the code need to be written to make everything as a Panel, Hans ? Code: How does the code need to be written to make everything as a Panel, Hans ?

Code:

```
class MusicNote : PictureBox
    {
        public string path = "ImagesName\\";
        public string noteShape = "";
        public int time = 0;

        public MusicNote(int iTime, string iNoteShape, int x, int y) : base()
        {
            noteShape = iNoteShape;
            time = iTime;
            Enabled = true;
            Location = new Point(x, y);
            Size = new Size(35, 35);
            Image NoteBmp = Image.FromFile(path + noteShape + ".png");
            Image = NoteBmp;

        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
        {
            base.OnPaint(pe);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The picture used is saved as transparent background and the MusicNote which is needed is there alone. Also it is saved as PNG format

Comment: This is in general not the right solution, not counting the transparency problem.  Your program will start sucking serious mud when every note is a picturebox.  Use the panel's Paint event instead, use e.Graphics.DrawImage() to draw the notes.

Comment: I agree with Hans. Also it's quite hard to actually make controls transparent in WinForms (it *can* be done, but it's a pain, and the results are usually sub-optimal). Can you post some examples of the types of graphics you want, and what you need to do as far as capturing user input etc. Perhaps then we can give you some more concrete examples of the code you might want to use in the Paint event etc. You also might want to look into WPF, which has better support for transparent controls and better graphics composition in general.

Comment: Check question again Hans Please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that must be done added in the main form is to add the controls of the PictureBox with those to the Panel.

```
Staff.Controls.Add(this.MNote);
```